# Recurrence Relations with non-constant coefficients

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

I have the following recurrence relations, modelling the movement of robots.
There are $n+1$ robots, $1$ to $n+1$.
Each robot $i$ with $2 \leq i \leq n$ has two neighbors, namely robots $i-1$
and $i+1$.
Robot $1$ has only the neighbor $2$.
Robot $n+1$ has only the neighbor $n$.

Robots move in discrete time steps (rounds).
In every round, robots $2$ to $n$ move to the midpoint between their neighbors.
The robots $1$ and $n+1$ move as far as possible away from their neighbors (the maximal allowed distance is $1$ and they cannot see the robot $n-1$ (3, respectively)).

The following recurrence relations describe the vector representation of the robot movement. 
The vector $v_i(t) = (x_i(t),y_i(t))$ is the vector pointing from robot $i$ to $i+1$ in time step $t$.
The following equations describe how $x_i(t)$ and $y_i(t)$ can be computed based on the time step $t-1$.

$x_1(t) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x_1(t-1)^2 + y_1(t-1)^2}} x_1(t-1) + \frac{1}{2} x_2(t-1)$

$x_i(t) = \frac{1}{2} x_{i-1}(t-1) + \frac{1}{2} x_{i+1}(t-1)$

$x_n(t) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x_n(t-1)^2 + y_n(t-1)^2}} x_n(t-1) + \frac{1}{2} x_{n-1}(t-1)$

$y_1(t) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x_1(t-1)^2 + y_1(t-1)^2}} y_1(t-1) + \frac{1}{2} y_2(t-1)$

$y_i(t) = \frac{1}{2} y_{i-1}(t-1) + \frac{1}{2} y_{i+1}(t-1)$

$y_n(t) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x_n(t-1)^2 + y_n(t-1)^2}} y_n(t-1) + \frac{1}{2} y_{n-1}(t-1)$

Moreover, for all $i$: $x_i(0)$ and $y_i(0)$ are initial values between $0$ and $1$.

Do you think that there is any chance to find a closed formula for this?

Comment: maybe anyone knows a tool that is able to solve this?

Comment: To get numerical values for any finite number of terms I would use some mathematical software (Matlab, Mathematica) or any programming language. Beyond that, not sure

Comment: What is $y$ in the definition of $x_1$ and $y_1$?

Comment: it is a $y_1$, thanks for the correction

Comment: Basically, it models the movement of robots. There are $n+1$ robots. The robots $2$ to $n$ have two neighbors (robot $i$ has neighbors $i-1$ and $i+1$). The first and the last robot have only one neighbor. The vector $(x_1(t), y_1(t))$ is the vector pointing from robot $1$ to robot $2$ at time step t. In every time step, all robots except of the first and the last robot move to the midpoint between their two neighbors. The first and the last robot move as far as possible away from their direct neighbors (the maximal possible distance is $1$).

Comment: And the equations above describe the change of the vector representation. Simulations indicate that this converges after a quadratic number of rounds, but I cannot prove this mathematically,...

Comment: Wait, is the time discrete in your problem? Then you probably should use an additional index for that instead of $x(t)$, which looks like time is continuous... I think the best approach to this kind of problem is direct simulation (I see, you've already done that)

Comment: Yes, $t$ is an integer. Thanks to simulations, I know this converges for $t \geq c \cdot n^2$ rounds, for a constant $c$. Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: You are welcome. I'll think more of it (though I doubt I could help). I think you should add that comment about robots to the post, it helps understand how the system works